# Linq to Entity Framework : unable to create a constant value of type ''. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to select from a table where list contains a value using linq and entity framework. but its telling me it cannot create a constant and throwing an exception. If you comment out the && list parts, it works fine.
What am I doing wrong?

```
var DbQry = (from data in Db.ACCESS
             where data.Active == true                                                                                                                             
                   && List.Select(s => s.Study).Contains(data.Study)
                   && List.Select(s => s.System).Contains(data.System)
             select data).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, the properties `Study` and `System` are classes (and not a primitive type) and `List` is a user defined variable.

If that's the case, can you try comparing with the identifiers like `List.Select(s => s.Study.Id).Contains(data.Study.Id)`